# Требовать удаления или удаление?

Tags: падежи

> Право позволяет требовать удаления личных данных.

Какой падеж необходимо употребить после слова "удаление"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Право позволяет требовать удаления личных данных.**

Согласно справочнику Розенталя (Управление в русском языке: Словарь-справочник), с указанным глаголом обычно используется Р.п. Например: требовать **внимания, объяснений**. Здоровье требовало теплого **климата**. Требовать правдивого **отражения** жизни в литературе.

В.п встречается реже (при конкретизации объекта): требовать **зарплату, книгу, пропуск, деньги.**